# DATE_ADD issue in PHP PDO MySQL - Login with OTP/2FA

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It should only update within 10 minutes of the current time on the created.

But when I tried to put any number on the database and not on the database, I received the error message "Invalid Security Code!".

so I changed to `AND NOW() <= DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)` then it's working fine.

Is there any way to only update within 10 minutes of the current time on the created instead of 8 hours?

Thank you!

```
try {
        $otp_code = $_POST["otp"];
        
        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table4 WHERE otp=:otp_code AND expired = 0 AND NOW() <= DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)");
            
        $statement->bindParam(":otp_code", $otp_code);
            
        $statement->execute();
        $count=$statement->rowCount();
        
        if(!empty($count)) {
            
            $data = [
                'expired' => 1,
                'otp_code' => $otp_code,
            ];
            
            $sql = "UPDATE $table4 SET expired=:expired WHERE otp=:otp_code";
            $stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute($data);
            
            $_SESSION['otp_code'] = $otp_code;
            
            header("Location: home.php");
        
        } else {
            $errorMessage = "Invalid Security Code!";
        }
        
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error : Check your error message.";
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
    }
```

Comment: There's no way for us to run or test the code, since a lot of information is still missing, so from our point of view replacing `DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)` by `DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)` should do the trick. This doesn't seem a very difficult problem to debug if you have access to your database.